# Standard method for creating file read/write 'library'?

Tags: excel, vba, io

I am attempting to create a file read/write 'library' using Excel VBA for an old file format.  Just for info, the format is LIS79, an old oil industry format for writing well-site data to tape - largely streams of wellbore measurements like density, resistance, temperature etc. The full spec is [here](http://w3.energistics.org/LIS/lis-79.pdf) (PDF doc) - it's pretty long and boring.

As I'm using Excel VBA I guess it's not really a library, but a collection of subs and functions etc.

I have been tapping away for a month or so and am making good progress, though it's becoming increasingly complicated - the number of subs and functions I need to write keeps on growing.

I figure I'm probably not the fist person to try and write a file read/write library from it's specification. So I've been searching StackExchange, searched using Google and browsed programming books at the local university library, to see if any sort of standard process or method might exist that would make the whole task a bit simpler.  Alas I haven't been able to find anything, though I have no formal programming background so it's possible I don't know precisely what to search for.

Does anyone know of a standard method, procedure or guidelines for creating file read/write libraries that you could refer me to?

Or is it just a matter of persevering - file read/write libraries can be long and complicated things to create?

Many thanks.

Comment: The only "standards" you should consider are in regard to "how" the library will be used, by whom(, and maybe how often). The general rule I use for this sort of interface is to model the read/write functions on existing "standard" library calls for reading/writing files (Windows, DOS, Linux, etc). Just pick one that makes sense for you, your company, your industry and that is likely to be well understood. When designing an API such as this, the most important thing is abstraction -- letting the library handle as much of the format-specific work as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info @PeterT, that's really helpful - given me some more things to read up on.  Cheers.